# sql oracle top 3 visited countries query from multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle

[image: Relational Diagram]

I designed a ticket booking system for flights. After I made some inserts, I want to write a query to show top 3 visited countries.

This is what I wrote:

```
select * from ( select flightnumber, count(*) as NumberOfFlights from ticket group by flightnumber order by NumberOfFlights desc) where rownum < 4;
```

My question is how to select Country column from Airport table such that to the current query result columns "FlightNumber" and "NumberOfFlights" to add "Country" name which corresponds to FlightNumber.

One example:
Airport table

```
insert into airport(icao_code, name, city, country) values ('PJAN', 'IS Airport', 'Iasi', 'Romania');
insert into airport(icao_code, name, city, country) values ('SBJN', 'SB Airport', 'Sibiu', 'Romania');
insert into airport(icao_code, name, city, country) values ('TMAN', 'TM Airport', 'Timisoara', 'Romania');
insert into airport(icao_code, name, city, country) values ('CJAN', 'CJ Airport', 'Cluj', 'Romania');
insert into airport(icao_code, name, city, country) values ('TKAN', 'TK Airport', 'Cluj', 'Turkey');
insert into airport(icao_code, name, city, country) values ('UKAN', 'UK Airport', 'London', 'UK');
insert into airport(icao_code, name, city, country) values ('ITAN', 'IT Airport', 'Roma', 'Italy');
insert into airport(icao_code, name, city, country) values ('SPAN', 'SP Airport', 'Madrid', 'Spain');
insert into airport(icao_code, name, city, country) values ('FRAN', 'FR Airport', 'Paris', 'France');
insert into airport(icao_code, name, city, country) values ('DEAN', 'DE Airport', 'Berlin', 'Germany');
insert into airport(icao_code, name, city, country) values ('GRAN', 'GR Airport', 'Athens', 'Greek');
```

Flight Table

```
insert into flight(flightnumber,departuretime,arrivaltime,distanceinkm,airportid_departure, airportid_arrival,numberofseats,airline_id) values
(1,to_date('2022/11/01 09:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS'),  to_date('2022/11/01 12:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS'), 1200,'PJAN', 'GRAN',500,231);
insert into flight(flightnumber,departuretime,arrivaltime,distanceinkm,airportid_departure, airportid_arrival,numberofseats,airline_id) values
(2,to_date('2022/02/15 08:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS'),  to_date('2022/02/16 12:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS'), 1200,'SBJN', 'GRAN',500,232);
insert into flight(flightnumber,departuretime,arrivaltime,distanceinkm,airportid_departure, airportid_arrival,numberofseats,airline_id) values
(3,to_date('2022/10/01 09:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS'),  to_date('2022/10/02 12:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS'), 1200,'GRAN', 'CJAN',400,232);
insert into flight(flightnumber,departuretime,arrivaltime,distanceinkm,airportid_departure, airportid_arrival,numberofseats,airline_id) values
(4,to_date('2022/09/01 09:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS'),  to_date('2022/09/02 12:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS'), 1200,'GRAN', 'TMAN',700,152);
insert into flight(flightnumber,departuretime,arrivaltime,distanceinkm,airportid_departure, airportid_arrival,numberofseats,airline_id) values
(5,to_date('2022/08/01 09:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS'),  to_date('2022/08/02 12:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS'), 1200,'PJAN', 'GRAN',600,231);

--Paris-Berlin/Berlin-Paris
insert into flight(flightnumber,departuretime,arrivaltime,distanceinkm,airportid_departure, airportid_arrival,numberofseats,airline_id) values
(6,to_date('2022/05/06 09:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS'),  to_date('2022/05/06 12:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS'), 800,'FRAN', 'DEAN',300,152);
insert into flight(flightnumber,departuretime,arrivaltime,distanceinkm,airportid_departure, airportid_arrival,numberofseats,airline_id) values
(7,to_date('2022/05/07 09:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS'),  to_date('2022/05/07 12:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS'), 800,'DEAN', 'FRAN',300,152);

-- Spain-Turkey/Turkey-Spain
insert into flight(flightnumber,departuretime,arrivaltime,distanceinkm,airportid_departure, airportid_arrival,numberofseats,airline_id) values
(8,to_date('2022/05/07 09:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS'),  to_date('2022/05/09 12:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS'), 4000,'SPAN', 'TKAN',800,112);
insert into flight(flightnumber,departuretime,arrivaltime,distanceinkm,airportid_departure, airportid_arrival,numberofseats,airline_id) values
(9,to_date('2022/05/08 09:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS'),  to_date('2022/05/10 12:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS'), 4000,'SPAN', 'TKAN',800,112);
insert into flight(flightnumber,departuretime,arrivaltime,distanceinkm,airportid_departure, airportid_arrival,numberofseats,airline_id) values
(10,to_date('2022/05/17 09:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS'),  to_date('2022/05/19 12:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS'), 4000,'TKAN', 'SPAN',800,112);
insert into flight(flightnumber,departuretime,arrivaltime,distanceinkm,airportid_departure, airportid_arrival,numberofseats,airline_id) values
(11,to_date('2022/05/18 09:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS'),  to_date('2022/05/20 12:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS'), 4000,'TKAN', 'SPAN',800,112);
```

Ticket table

```
insert into ticket(ticketnumber, price, confirmationcode, flightnumber, passengerid) values
(1,200,'1232sde2asmd',7,37);
insert into ticket(ticketnumber, price, confirmationcode, flightnumber, passengerid) values
(2,210,'1232sde2asnd',7,36);
insert into ticket(ticketnumber, price, confirmationcode, flightnumber, passengerid) values
(3,250,'1232sde2astd',7,35);
insert into ticket(ticketnumber, price, confirmationcode, flightnumber, passengerid) values
(4,270,'1232sde2as2d',7,34);
insert into ticket(ticketnumber, price, confirmationcode, flightnumber, passengerid) values
(5,280,'1232sde2as0d',4,33);
insert into ticket(ticketnumber, price, confirmationcode, flightnumber, passengerid) values
(6,300,'1232sde2as9d',4,32);
insert into ticket(ticketnumber, price, confirmationcode, flightnumber, passengerid) values
(7,100,'1232sdv2as3d',4,31);
insert into ticket(ticketnumber, price, confirmationcode, flightnumber, passengerid) values
(8,200,'1232vde2as4d',1,30);
insert into ticket(ticketnumber, price, confirmationcode, flightnumber, passengerid) values
(9,120,'1252sde2as3d',2,29);
insert into ticket(ticketnumber, price, confirmationcode, flightnumber, passengerid) values
(10,290,'1232sde2ax3d',3,28);
insert into ticket(ticketnumber, price, confirmationcode, flightnumber, passengerid) values
(11,50,'1232sdy2as3d',3,27);
insert into ticket(ticketnumber, price, confirmationcode, flightnumber, passengerid) values
(12,90,'1232sae2as3d',6,26);
```

In the Ticket table I inserted 4 flights to France, 3 flights to Greece and another 2 to Greece (my mistake). It should be another Country.

So my query gives me:

```
FlightNumber     NumberOfFlights
7                  4
4                  3
3                  2
```

I want a result like that:

```
FlightNumber    Country                            NumberOfFlights
7             France                                  4
4             Greece                                  3
3             Greece(mistake,some random country)     2
```

Comment: SQL Server or Oracle?

Comment: I've *assumed* Oracle, based on the title.

Comment: @Larnu I've assumed Oracle based on the syntax `to_date`

Comment: With top n queries you must always decide how to deal with ties. If the top vited countries had 4, 4, 3, and 3 visits, while all others had 2 visits or less, which would you want to show? Only the two with 4 visits? The four countries? The two countries with for visits plus one of the countries with three visits arbitrarily picked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the tables together, then group by the country.

On Oracle 12c you can even use the newer `offset` syntax, and this will work in SQL Server also.

```sql
select
  a.country,
  count(*) as NumberOfTickets
from ticket as t
join flight as f on f.flightnumber = t.flightnumber
join airport as a on a.icao_code = f.airportid_arrival
group by
  a.country
order by
  NumberOfFlights desc
offset 0 rows fetch next 3 rows only;
```

If you wanted to get the top three *flights*, you could add `flightnumber` to the `group by`

```sql
select
  t.flightnumber,
  a.country,
  count(*) as NumberOfTickets
from ticket as t
join flight as f on f.flightnumber = t.flightnumber
join airport as a on a.icao_code = f.airportid_arrival
group by
  t.flightnumber,
  a.country
order by
  NumberOfFlights desc
offset 0 rows fetch next 3 rows only;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1b9b65b993d798fb490f13dcbccd34a8)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using oracle rank function.  Something like this for oracle 11g:

```
select *
 from (select country, flightCnt, dense_rank () over( order by flightCnt) as rnk
  from (select a.country, count(f.flightNumber) as flightCnt
    from ticket t, flight f, airport a
    where t.flightNumber = f.flightNumber
    and f.airportId_arrival = a.icao_code
    group by a.country)
  )
where rnk < 4
;
```